# Strange behavior when passing Array<String> as varargs with spread operator

Tags: kotlin

I've only just started Kotlin and now have to figure out something about a function requiring `varargs` of the type String. The problematic code is as follows:

```
val optionStrArr = arrayOfNulls<String>(options.size)
for (i in options.indices) {
    optionStrArr[i] = options[i].value
}
App.instance?.analyticPollReceive(pollID!!, title!!, question!!, *optionStrArr)

...

fun analyticPollReceive(id: String, title: String, question: String, vararg options: String) {
    // function body
}
```

This is just part of the code that was converted from Java by Android Studio's Java-Kotlin converter.

The error is in the function call, where, if I remove the spread operator, the compiler says:

> `Type mismatch. Required: String; Found: Array<String?>`

However, when I put that spread operator in, the compiler says:

> `Type mismatch. Required: Array<out String>; Found: Array<String?>`

Should I just change the vararg type to `vararg options: String?`?

Comment: No. You should avoid nulls as much as you can. So your array should be a String array, and not a String? array.

Comment: Depends, can `options[i].value` ever be null? If not then `optionStrArr` should be of type `Array<String>`. Otherwise you need to change the vararg type to `Array<String?>`.

Comment: Actually, `options[i]` is an Object itself, and I just changed the value from `String?` to `String`. But when I pass the resulting array into the varargs argument, the compiler still thinks it's an `Array<String?>`. Though maybe it's just me needing to delete the original Java files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because in Java any String variable can also be null. In Kotlin you have different types for non nullable (`String`) and nullabe (`String?`) variables.

In your case it depends on what type `options[i].value` is. If it can never be `null`, then you can change the type of `optionStrArr` to `Array<String>` and the code will work fine. You can create array of `Strings` this way:

```
val optionStrArr = Array<String>(options.size) { options[it].value }
```

If `options[i].value` is of type `String?`, then you either change the vararg type of `analyticPollReceive()`, if it makes sense for that function to receive nullable array. Otherwise you have to rethink why do you have a nullable array that you want to pass to a function that does not want nulls.

Comment: Well, since I've changed the String type of `options[i].value` to `String` instead of `String?`, I suppose I'll take the first option [`val optionStrArr = Array<String>(options!!.size, {options[it].value})`, if that's the right syntax]. Thanks. By the way, does Kotlin's `String` mean `@NonNull String` in Java? Does `String?` mean `@Nullable String`?

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337 Yes that is how it works. You should read some basics about Kotlin before you continue with porting your Java code to Kotlin, so you will understand all the weird syntax the converter will generate, because all types are nullable in Java. Once you have most of your code in Kotlin and you have nullable types only when actually needed, your code will look much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The second error you see is because you initialise the Array with `arrayOfNulls<String>`. That will create an `Array<String?>` since it has to be filled with nulls.

To fix it, look into other ways to create the array, such as `Collection#toTypedArray` or `Array#copyOf` (depending on what type `options` actually is.
These will generate an array of the same type as the source, and not implicitly make it nullable.

Answer (score 0):

The array's `optionStrArr` type is `Array<String?>`.  
So you need to make this change:

```
fun analyticPollReceive(id: String, title: String, question: String, vararg options: String?) {
    // function body
}
```